# Which verb form comes after 'than'?

Tags: verb-forms

I've found infinitive,  bare infinitive and gerund. For example

> He did more than **ask** questions.
>
> It's better **to ask** than **to assume**.
>
> **Going to work** is often better than **going to class**.
>
> It's a better choice than **going to hostel**.

What is the rule to determine which form is suitable?

Comment: Than is used several ways. All of them are correct in those sentences. "X is better than" or "do more than" are comparatives. It works with verbs or nouns. "Going to a hostel" is a noun phrase.  It's better to ask is a to-infinitive and can be compared to another to-infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

"Than" is a "multi-purpose" word, and it does not require a strict sentence format.

All the examples you provided are OK.